# How to use laravel array in chartist.js script

Tags: javascript, arrays, laravel

My laravel array is in the wrong format for Chartist.js script to process as labels.  As my labels are strings (sales persons name) they are wrapped in quotes and never get read by chartist script properly.

I've tried encoding as json and replacing " with ', but they are still read as 
`&quot; Sales Person &quot;` around the sting values.

Numbers work fine, however strings are very difficult to use with Chartist.

Laravel collection

`$advisors_raw = Paymentplan::distinct()->whereNotNull('owner')->orderBy('owner', 'asc')->pluck('owner');`

Chartist Script that wont read array:

```
new Chartist.Bar('#chart3', {
  labels: [{{$advisors_raw}}],
  series: [{{$pruchase_total_2019}}],
});
```

Comment: Please show us a sample of what the output is, that would guide us in helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Showing us a sample would guide us better but you should try using this instead

```
new Chartist.Bar('#chart3', {
  labels: {!!$advisors_raw!!},
  series: {!!$pruchase_total_2019!!},
});
```

**Edit removed square brackets